# iOS custom gallery

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, gallery

Sorry, I've asked a similar question but I'm already suffering 3 days dealing with a simple photo gallery in my app. I just need a gallery with array of 1024x768 images, a gallery that will fit pictures properly into the screen.
I've tried

- ATPagingView - worked fine but an 1024x768 image couldn't be resized properly for both orientations.
- MWPhotobrowser - didn't managed to connect because i'm using ARC, even if I disabled arc for added files, there was a compile error I coudn't get rid of.
- Custom UIScrollView with pages, with a scrollView for each page and imageview inside it, but it didn't help.
  Please, help me somehow, did somebody make galleries like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found KTPhotoBrowser classes. They are nice and well-documented. I implemented the very simple photo browsing gallery very fast. Images are now resized properly, everything is okay. if you want a gallery, try this, for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Give [Nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus) a try. It is an open source framework that is run by jverkoey, ex Three20 guy. It is not ARC'd yet, but you can turn ARC off for compilation and that works just fine, plus they are moving to ARC soon, already have a git branch of it. It has a photoviewer class but I've not used it yet, but I will need to, that's only one of the reasons I'm using it. Pretty happy with it so far!

Comment: Thanks, I already found KTPhotoBrowser classes. They are nice and doceumented.